# Autollenado con doble clic

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

estoy haciendo un formulario en el cual al momento de ingresar el "rpe" de un trabajador, en automatico me arroje el nombre, categoria y plaza, y al parecer la busqueda funciona, porque al ingresar el rpe me muestra las sugerencias, el detalle viene cuando al dar doble clic, no me arroja en automatico los datos, nose que estoy haciendo mal, espero me puedan ayudar, los codigos son los siguientes:

ARCHIVO getRPE.php en donde se ingresan apenas los caracteres del RPE y comienzan a salir las coincidencias de la base de datos

```
    <?php
    $servername = "";
    $database = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";

    $connection =                                         
    mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);

    if(isset($_GET['term']))
    {
    $buscar_nombre = buscar_nombre($connection, $_GET['term']);
    $rpe_list = array();
    foreach($buscar_nombre as $nombre)
    {
        $rpe_list[] = $nombre['rpe'];
    }
    echo json_encode($rpe_list);
    }

    function buscar_nombre($connection, $term)
    {
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM trabajadores WHERE rpe LIKE                         
    '%".$term."%'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($connection,$consulta);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_all($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $data;
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);

    ?>
```

ARCHIVO buscarNombreCat.php aquí es donde hago el autollenado de los campos que se supone se llenan en automático

```
    <?php

    // consigue el nombre desde el formulario
    $buscar_rpe = $_REQUEST['rpe'];

    $servername = "";
    $database = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";

                    
   $conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);

    if ($buscar_rpe !== "") 
    {
    // Se busca el nombre y la categoria correspondiente al rpe
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM trabajadores WHERE rpe='$buscar_rpe'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);

    // consigue el nombre, lo que va dentro de row es como se         llama el campo en la tabla trabajadores
    $nombre = $row['nombre'];

    // consigue la categoria, lo que va dentro de row es como se llama el campo de categoria en la tabla trabajadores
    $categoria = $row['categoria'];

    // consigue la plaza, lo que va dentro de row es como se llama el campo de categoria en la tabla trabajadores
    $plaza = $row['plaza'];
    }
    else
    {
    header("Location: lectura.php");
    }

    // lo almacena un un arreglo
    $result = array("$nombre", "$categoria", "$plaza");

    // lo envia al formulario
    $myJSON = json_encode($result);
    echo $myJSON;
    mysqli_close($connection);
    ?>
```

ARCHIVO index.php y aquí es donde siento que está la falla.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Propuestas CFE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilosindex2.css">
    </head>

    <header>

    <div class="logos">
    <img src="Imagenes/logo Golfo Centro blanco.png" alt="logo de la empresa" class="logo-img">
    <h2 class="nombre" >SIPROT</h2>
    <img src="Imagenes/suterm.png" alt="logo del sindicato" class="logo-img">
</div>

    </header>

    <body>
    <button class="btnsesion" title="cerrar" name="cerrar" value="" >Cerrar Sesión</button>
    <form id="transactionForm" method="POST" action="scripts.php">
    <h1>LLene la información solicitada</h1>
    <div class="Formulario"><label for="Motivos">Motivado de</label>
        <select name="Motivos" id="Motivos">
            <option value="Comision Oficial"> Comisión Oficial </option>  
            <option value="Capacitación y Adiestramiento"> Capacitación y Adiestramiento </option>  
            <option value="Vacaciones de Ley"> Vacaciones de Ley </option>  
            <option value="Vacaciones de Contrato"> Vacaciones de Contrato </option>  
            <option value="Incapacidad por accidente de trabajo"> Incapacidad por accidente de trabajo </option>  
            <option value="Incapacidad por enfermedad general"> Incapacidad por enfermedad general </option> 
            <option value="Incapacidad por maternidad"> Incapacidad por maternidad </option>  
            <option value="Permiso por fallecimiento familiar"> Permiso por fallecimiento familiar </option> 
            <option value="Permiso por Comité Ejecutivo SUTERM"> Permiso por Comité Espc. SUTERM </option> 
            <option value="Permiso por paternidad"> Permiso por paternidad </option> 
            <option value="Permiso particular (Permiso sin goce)"> Permiso particular (Permiso sin goce) </option> 
            <option value="Suspensión por sanción"> Suspensión por sanción </option>
            <option value="Falta injustificada"> Falta injustificada</option> 
        </select>
   </div> 
    <div class="Formulario"><label>*R.P.E.</label> <input type="text" id="rpe" name="rpe" ondblclick="Doble_Clic(this.value)" value=""></div>
    <div class="Formulario"><label>Nombre</label> <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" value=""></div>
    <div class="Formulario"><label>Categoría</label> <input type="text" id="categoria" name="categoria" value=""></div>
    <div class="Formulario"><label for="Plaza">Plaza</label> <input id="plaza" name="plaza" value=""></div>
    <div class="Formulario"><label for="Propuesta">*Se propone a</label> <input id="Propuesta" name="Propuesta"></div>
    <div class="Formulario"><label for="Suplente">*Nombre</label> <input id="Suplente" name="Suplente"></div>
    <div class="Formulario"><label for="PeriodoInicial">Periodo del</label> <input id="PeriodoInicial" type="date" name="PeriodoInicial">
        <div class="Formulario"><label for="PeriodoFinal">al</label> <input id="PeriodoFinal" type="date" name="PeriodoFinal"></div></div>
    <div class="Formulario">
        <button for="boton2" type="reset">Cancelar</button>
        <button for="boton" type="submit">Solicitar</button>
    </div>
</form>

<!-- jQuery --> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#rpe" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'getRPE.php',
        });
    });
</script>       

<!-- ESTE SCRIPT REALIZA EL AUTOLLENADO DEL Nombre, Categoria y Plaza LUEGO DE HACER DOBLE CLIK -->
<script>
     function Doble_Clic(str) 
     alert(str);
{
    if (str.length == 0)    
    {
        document.getElementById("nombre").value = "";
        document.getElementById("categoria").value = "";
        document.getElementById("plaza").value = "";
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)              
            {
                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById                         
                ("nombre").value = myObj[0];                    
                document.getElementById
                ("categoria").value = myObj[1];
                document.getElementById
                ("plaza").value = myObj[2];             
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "buscarNombreCat.php?rpe=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
    </script>
    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: El código como texto, no como imágenes. Lee [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Gracias por la observación, ya puse el código como texto